# Scrape website's Power BI dashboard using Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, powerbi

I'm trying to scrape a PowerBI dashboard [here](https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNzA0MGM4NGMtN2E5Ny00NDU3LWJiNzMtOWFlMGIyMDczZjg2IiwidCI6IjM4MmZiOGIwLTRkYzMtNDEwNy04MGJkLTM1OTViMjQzMmZhZSIsImMiOjZ9&pageName=ReportSection) where I need to first select an occupation and select all States and then scrape the entire underneath table using Selenium.

[image]

This screenshot shows the PowerBI dashboard that I'm trying to scrape. After selecting one occupation under `Job Name`, select `Select all` for the `State`, then there is a table that loads up on the bottom of the page that I would like to scrape.

Currently, my code could not locate the selection criteria and could not scrape the data from the scroll down table.

Any help or hints would be much appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
driver.get("https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNzA0MGM4NGMtN2E5Ny00NDU3LWJiNzMtOWFlMGIyMDczZjg2IiwidCI6IjM4MmZiOGIwLTRkYzMtNDEwNy04MGJkLTM1OTViMjQzMmZhZSIsImMiOjZ9&pageName=ReportSection")

# Find and click the first two elements
##occupation
wait_for_element(By.XPATH, "//body/div[@id='pbiAppPlaceHolder']/report-embed[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/exploration-container[1]/div[1]/div[1]/docking-container[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/exploration-host[1]/div[1]/div[1]/exploration[1]/div[1]/explore-canvas[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]").click()
##all states
wait_for_element(By.XPATH, "//body/div[@id='pbiAppPlaceHolder']/report-embed[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/exploration-container[1]/div[1]/div[1]/docking-container[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/exploration-host[1]/div[1]/div[1]/exploration[1]/div[1]/explore-canvas[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]").click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this way:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNzA0MGM4NGMtN2E5Ny00NDU3LWJiNzMtOWFlMGIyMDczZjg2IiwidCI6IjM4MmZiOGIwLTRkYzMtNDEwNy04MGJkLTM1OTViMjQzMmZhZSIsImMiOjZ9&pageName=ReportSection")

# wait for the dashboard to load
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'transform.bringToFront')))

state = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="State"]')
state.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[title="Select all"]').click()

job_name = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Job Name"]')
# for example, select the option 4
job_name.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-row-index="4"]').click()

time.sleep(2)
# your desired table
table = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.mid-viewport')[1]
```

Few points to note:

1. We first wait for the dashboard on the webpage to be visible.
2. Next, locate the `State` web element and find `Select all` option in it to click.
3. Similarly, locate the `Job Name` web element and find the option number `4` in it to click.

The variable `table` holds the desired web element of the table you want to scrape which you can use for further parsing to extract the table's data.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks so much for the help. I also have another problem since the table is dynamic and can scroll to the rightmost and downward, I am using     `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollLeft = arguments[0].scrollWidth", table)`
and `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", table)` manage to scroll the table so that I can scrape the entire table but fail to do so. Could you kindly suggest how to do so?

Comment: I am having the same issue as mentioned in comment above. What's the best way to handle the dynamic scrolling? Thanks.

Comment: @Code and j413254, I have uploaded the solution with horizontal rightmost and vertical downward scrolling in order to load all the table data on my GitHub here:  https://github.com/ajeet214/Web_Scraping_with_Selenium/blob/main/app_powerbi_com.py